# Multiple like in a laravel mongo db package not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a project which is creating in laravel and mongodb. I am using a package for connecting to mongodb "https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb". I have a table listing. In this table listing there is a text box for search data. For that I used **like** feature. I have followed the same in documentation but not working. When I search **invoice_number** data is getting empty. But when I search **beds** data is getting perfectly. Please correct me.

```
$bookings = Booking::select('invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid')
                ->where('is_delete', 0)
                ->where('invoice_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('beds', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->skip($start)
                ->take($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` statements in your query translate to this:

`WHERE [cond_1] AND [cond_2] OR [cond_3]`

I doubt this is the condition you need. I'd say you want this:

`WHERE [cond_1] AND ([cond_2] OR [cond_3])` -- notice the brackets.

To achieve this, you need a closure in your Builder query. Try this:

```
$bookings = Booking::select('invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid')
        ->where('is_delete', 0)
        ->where(function($query) use ($search) { /* That's the closure */
            $query->where('invoice_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('beds', 'like', "%{$search}%");
         })
        ->skip($start)
        ->take($limit)
        ->orderBy($order, $dir)
        ->get();
```

And an **[example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping)** from the docs.

Comment: Thanks. Initially I got error `Undefined variable: search`. I have added small changes like `function($query, $search)`. But still i am getting error like `Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\BookingController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), called in X:\xampp\htdocs\cabinapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 207 and defined`

Comment: My bad. The `$search` needs to be passed to the closure. Updated the query.